# Antlr: cleaning up string tokens in the lexer?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm writing a combined grammar which has the standard STRING token defined in the Definitive Guide;

```
STRING: '"' (ESC|.)*? '"' ;
fragment
ESC : '\\"' | '\\\\' ; // 2-char sequences \" and \\
```

One thing I notice is that the STRING token's `.Text` property is always the quoted, escaped form seen in the input, like so;

```
// from grammar like rule: title:STRING;
var title = context.title.Text; // == \"my string\"
```

This means I'd have to 'correct' the string in the parser, stripping off the quotes and handling escape characters, wherever I refer to a string token. And that feels like a lexing job done in the parser.

I wonder if there's a way to alter the output of the lexer, so that the lexer token can show cleansed content? I notice there's a lot of possible overrides available on the generated lexer, but I noticed that `IToken.Text` is read-only, so I can't see how to alter it.

Other places where this would be useful are in;

- double-quoted strings like `"foo"`.
- single-quotes strings like `'sql string'`.
- variable references like `$foo` where the interesting text is `foo`.

Comment: see https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=5373959

Answer (score 0):

You may also check if the token implements `WritableToken` and the set the value.

See the java doc [here](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/WritableToken.html).

Or the C# source [here](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs/blob/master/runtime/CSharp/Antlr4.Runtime/IWritableToken.cs).

The [CommonToken](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/CommonToken.html) implements `(I)WritableToken`.